# Опасен ли javascript в URL?

Tags: url, javascript, безопасность

Речь пойдёт не про текст ссылки, который защитить просто, а про адрес ссылки.

1. Может ли javascript как-то в URL передаваться и исполняться сразу? Делаю, чтобы пользователи могли ссылки добавлять на сайт, и подумала, а что если формат ссылки будет javascript: ла ла ла, или http://javascript: ла ла ла, опасно ли это?
2. Даже если сам по себе javascript в URL не опасен, то может быть он может стать таким при выводе такой ссылки на страницу?
3. От чего очищать ссылку чтобы из неё не сделали опасную ссылку? Чтобы не вписали в неё javascript код, который потом исполнится на странице.
4. Проверить чтобы ссылка вела на сайт, а не на файл, я так представляю - невозможно, да? Потому что даже если регулярочками запретить ссылаться на все форматы файлов, ничто не помешает ссылаться на страницу, которая выдаёт файл заголовками и всё такое.

Только что нашла уязвимость. Если в адрес  ссылки передать кавычки, то можно закрыть ссылку и далее дописать title, например. Пример в качестве адреса указать " title="Хы хы хы"

То есть, надо кавычки вырезать - как минимум. Что ещё?

Comment: > Только что нашла уязвимость

С этого надо было начинать "ввод никак не проверяется" :-) Но это уже другая страшная сказка.

Comment: @karmadro4 теги и кавычки вырежу, что-нибудь ещё? :) Или просто проверять адрес на соответствие регулярному выражению? Боюсь, слишком большое выраженище получится, если все детали учесть. :)

Comment: Таки говорю же, это уже мало относится к борьбе с инъекцией букмарклетов. Читайте [сюда](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно не разрешать [псевдо]схему `javascript:` в URI. Прочтите [сюда](http://xkr.us/js/links) на тему почему это неправильно. Так и только так скрипт выполняется непосредственно из URI.

Comment: @karmadro4

То есть, если запретить передавать в ссылке javascript: то всё будет хорошо? А как быть с data: ?

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, `data:` фактически создает новый документ, так что будут действовать ограничения same-origin и, например, куки украсть не удастся.